# simplehtmldom get href of a title

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I have a code below which is working correctly but is missing one thing. It is not returning the value for the `$item['link']` which is the `href` of the title.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://news.google.com/news/section?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&q=newzealand'); 


foreach($html->find('.blended-wrapper') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->find('span.titletext', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['source']    = $article->find('span.esc-lead-article-source', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['clip'] = $article->find('div.esc-lead-snippet-wrapper', 0)->plaintext;

    $item['link'] = $article->find('.esc-lead-article-title a')->href;

    $articles[] = $item;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($articles);
echo "<pre/>";
```

This is what it outputs, as you see the link key is empty. I've tried so many things.
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => New Zealand dominate 2011 after 24 years of pain
            [source] => Times of India
            [clip] => WELLINGTON: After 24 years of stumbles, disappointments and plain old chokes, New Zealand finally lived up to their billing as world rugby's premier side in 2011.
            [link] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => PRESS DIGEST-New Zealand newspapers - Dec 29
            [source] => Reuters
            [clip] => WELLINGTON Dec 29 (Reuters) - Following are some of the lead stories from New Zealand metropolitan newspapers on Thursday. Stories may be taken from either the paper or Internet editions of the papers.
            [link] => 
        )
```

Comment: This is the only one where you use space. Mey this will work:
`$article->find('.esc-lead-article-title')->find('a')->href`

Comment: Just a guess, `$item['link'] = $article->find('.esc-lead-article-title a',0)->href;`

Comment: Thanks guys, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the first one of the links, even though there's only one in the collection:

```
$item['link'] = $article->find('.esc-lead-article-title a', 0)->href;
```

Even though simple_html_dom is modeled after jQuery, it's API does not map exactly to jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, but that actually does not work. I had the `0` there before and has not worked. thanks for the effort though

Comment: @acrobat - If you look at the souce code of that Google page, you'll see that there's no space before the class attribute e.g. `<a target="_blank"class="...` vs. `<a target="_blank" class="...`. It seems this is what throws off the simple_html_dom parser. You'll see that your anchor (simple_html_dom) object does have a `target` property, but not a `class` or `href` property.